I have issues to install the viennaRNA package to be use on python
I am trying to use the package viennaRNA in python but I have an issue installing it.
I am getting this error message:
C:\Users\marvi>py -m pip install viennarna
Collecting viennarna
  Using cached ViennaRNA-2.6.4.tar.gz (5.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: viennarna
  Building wheel for viennarna (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for viennarna (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\RNA
      copying interfaces\Python\RNA\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\RNA
      copying interfaces\Python\RNA\RNA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\RNA
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ViennaRNA
      copying interfaces\Python\ViennaRNA\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\ViennaRNA
      running egg_info
      writing ViennaRNA.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to ViennaRNA.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to ViennaRNA.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'ViennaRNA.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'COPYING'
      adding license file 'AUTHORS'
      writing manifest file 'ViennaRNA.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      building 'RNA._RNA' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for viennarna
Failed to build viennarna
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (viennarna)

I tried to install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 like indicated but it changed nothing.
I was able to install other packages. Could you help me?
